# Python Read XML file as key-value

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml

Given XML formatted data I want to read it in key-value fromat.

For example, Given:

```
<note>
<to>Tove</to>
<from>Jani</from>
<heading>Reminder</heading>
<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
<example></example>
</note>
```

I want to have:

```
[[to, Tove], [from, Jani], [heading, Reminder], [body, Don't forget me this weekend!], [example, ]]
```

As you can see I have not included note in my output as it doesn't have a matching key.

Comment: Your desired output, is not valid python.

Comment: @Julien it's a list, just removed `'` for simplicity...

Answer (score 1):

Please note that the the expected output mentioned in your OP is not a valid python syntax. But I assume that you need a list of list(with two string objects, `tag` and `text`). If that's the case, you can use built-in [`xml.etree.ElementTree`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#parsing-xml) module.

```
>>> import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
>>>
>>> s = """
... <note>
... <to>Tove</to>
... <from>Jani</from>
... <heading>Reminder</heading>
... <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
... <example></example>
... </note>
... """
>>>
>>>
>>> [[child.tag, child.text if child.text else ""] for child in ET.fromstring(s)]
[['to', 'Tove'], ['from', 'Jani'], ['heading', 'Reminder'], ['body', "Don't forget me this weekend!"], ['example', '']]
```

Comment: Sorry it didn't work for ```"<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<note>
  <to>Tove</to>
  <from>Jani</from>
  <heading>Reminder</heading>
  <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>"```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `xmltodict` to convert it to a dictionary:

```py
xml_text = """<note>
<to>Tove</to>
<from>Jani</from>
<heading>Reminder</heading>
<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
<example></example>
</note>"""

import xmltodict

xml_dict = xmltodict.parse(xml_text)
print(xml_dict)
# {'note': {'to': 'Tove', 'from': 'Jani', 'heading': 'Reminder', 'body': "Don't forget me this weekend!", 'example': None}}
```

You can then access each value by name:

```py
xml_dict['note']['from'] -> 'Jani'
```

Comment: This isn't what I asked for... the output isn't the same